# Формат даты javascript

Tags: javascript

JSON.parse представляет дату в формате

> 2017-01-09T14:02:25.207

В документе дат много, применять к каждой функцию toLocaleDateString не оптимально. Как привести формат всех дат в документе? Например к такому

> 09.01.2017

Comment: `JSON.parse` не парсит даты, обычно. Он оставляет их строкой, которая приходит с сервера

Comment: @Grundy энивей, формат не устраивает, должны же в JS быть средства это исправить

Comment: _toLocaleDateString_ - один из вариантов приведения _даты_ к нужному формату. Раз уж дата возвращается с сервера - если она нужна только для вывода - пусть сервер и возвращает сразу в нужном формате. Сейчас не понятно как ты получаешь данные, применяешь к ним parse, и как потом хочешь использовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если же, как сказал Grundy не возможно получить нужный формат с сервера, то можно вот так:

```js
var date = '2017-01-09T14:02:25.207';

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  var new_date = date.replace(/^(\d+)\-(\d+)\-(\d+)\D.+$/, '$3.$2.$1'); // Преобразовываем дату
  
  console.log(new_date);
};
```

```html
<button>Показать дату</button>
```

Comment: И чем этот способ лучше toLocaleDateString?

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев, я говорил, что он лучше?

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев, например тем, что не нужно приводить строку в дату. в то время как _toLocaleDateString_ - это метод даты, а не строки